# Can I write a custom allocator to decide the reallocation amount of std::vector?

Tags: c++, memory-management, vector, allocator, c++-concepts

To my understanding, a custom allocator must fit the requierements of the [Allocator Concept](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Allocator).  Based on that interface though, I can't see how I would choose a new allocation amount when the vector has run out of reserve.

For example,  the current implementation on my machine will double the allocation size every time the `reserve` is exceeded during a `push_back()`.   I'd like to provide a custom allocator that is slow and memory conscious.  It will only allocate the previous `capacity+1` to accomodate the new element.

These are the interfaces of the concept I'm looking at:

```
a.allocate(n)
a.allocate(n, cvptr) (optional)
```

I've made a working boilerplate allocator like so:

```
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>

template <class T> class MyAlloc {
public:

  // type definitions
  typedef T value_type;
  typedef T *pointer;
  typedef const T *const_pointer;
  typedef T &reference;
  typedef const T &const_reference;
  typedef std::size_t size_type;
  typedef std::ptrdiff_t difference_type;

  pointer address(reference value) const {
    return &value;
  }
  const_pointer address(const_reference value) const {
    return &value;
  }
  size_type max_size() const throw() {
    return std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max() / sizeof(T);
  }
  pointer allocate(size_type num, const void * = 0) {
    return (pointer)(::operator new(num * sizeof(T)));
  }
  void construct(pointer p, const T &value) {
    new ((void *)p) T(value);
  }
  void destroy(pointer p) {
    p->~T();
  }
  void deallocate(pointer p, size_type num) {
    ::operator delete((void *)p);
  }
};
```

Looking at the `allocate` function:

```
pointer allocate(size_type num, const void * = 0) {
  return (pointer)(::operator new(num * sizeof(T)));
}
```

I could allocate more or less memory here, but I don't see a way of reporting that back to the vector so that it knows what its current capacity is.

Maybe this falls outside the responsibility of an allocator?

Comment: Honestly, what do you think? (Imagine that `malloc(10)` would return 6 bytes, because it doesn't think you need all 10 bytes...)

Comment: IMHO, the strategy to allocate more than the memory needed in push_back is a responsability of the vector class. The allocator has the responsability to find the amount of memory needed.

Comment: Actually, I would consider your implementation a wrong implementation of the vector class because the interface of this class includes the amortized O(1) efficience of the push_back method.

Comment: What @AntonioGarrido said: I feel this is the responsability of the vector class. Methods like  `reserve` and `capacity` give you a better control on the growth (albeit not perfect, `reserve` can allocate more than requested). Also, I'm not sure that realloc'ng the vector every push is memory efficient on the long run (fragmentation?). Intuitively, I feel that if your objects are very large to allocate, your vector should hold pointers to them. This way, *you* would control the effective allocations of your large objects.

Comment: Yeah, its not necessarily a good idea. I wanted to see if it was possible though for some memory constrained hardware(where speed is not an issue).  I suppose I can could `reserve()` before every `push_back()`.  That would prevent the memory from doubling too high.

Comment: Please be aware that the resulting capacity after a call to `reserve(n)` is allowed to be greater than `n`. A conforming implementation may choose to allocate up to the next power of two (effectively doubling the capacity). Actually, it would make sense for an implementation of `push_back` to check the capacity and to call `reserve` with the new size as a parameter if the capacity is not enough.

Comment: I tested, and at least on my box (up to date archlinux), `reserve()` does not over-allocate (while `push_back()` does), so it **is** possible to call reserve manually before a push to grow one element at a time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The STL model that C++ inherited is based on a specific division between container and allocator. The purpose of an allocator is to provide the memory that someone requests. The decision about how much memory to allocate is entirely up to the container, without regard for which allocator it uses to provide that memory.

That's the model C++ uses. You could write your own `vector`-like container that allows its allocator to specify how much it should allocate. But other than that, no.